# How can I make my button display correctly on all media devices?

Tags: android, ios, css, media-queries

I have a website that has a different theme from its mobile site.

They share the same content and plugin , but different themes.

I have 3 buttons that are on my mobile site that shows clear only on certain phones.

when I pull up the site on a different phone, sometimes the buttons look smashed together and almost like the dont have css linked to them

why does this happen on certain phones , idk.....

the buttons say "search jobs" "employers"  "candidates"

what could this be, please help

https://hughesjobs.net

Comment: you have media css in your website?

Comment: please take a look and send a screen shot of the buttons you see display... i will post the url at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Phones have different operating systems and (very likely) different web-browsers. Each browser hast its very unique default-css-files embedded. If you do not specify your css entirely, then a browser will "fall back" to its own unique default-css-file (at least regarding the undefined css properties).

This happens a lot with Iphones, Ipads, etc.

Mobile devices have (again) their own css-properties.

Your question is regarding the consistent design of buttons.
The answer is: debug on different devices AND be 100% specific about all css properties.

BR

update:

according to your code, this detailed css-styling should make your buttons look the same in different browsers:

```
.containerm button {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #BBB;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: by looking at my url , would you be able to determine this ... i entered my url into this question just now.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the case with your website. On my Iphone6 your buttons look full-width 100% and very closely stacked together.

Comment: You may want to address properties like: width, height, padding and margin with YOUR standards. was this helpful to you? please let me know and upvote my Answer if everything is clear now. :)

Comment: can you be more exact?

Comment: updated my answer. please update your code and re-try to access with different devices. let me know your status. br